# Too few parameters. Expected 1 - but I have one

Tags: vba, ms-access, parameters, ms-access-2010, recordset

So I've recently been working on a VBA script to transfer an entire database of student medical records from their old one-table, 68-field, flat system to a new dynamic system with 24 related tables.

There was no issue for the first few tables, but then I ran into this. The line of code throwing the error is:

```
Set rstFrom = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select " & Flat & ".Student," & Flat & ".School," & Flat & ".Social," & Flat & ".FamilyHist from " & Flat & " WHERE 1=1")`
```

`Flat` is a String which stores the name of the flat database (this is because I'm working with a dummy database so they will need a convenient and quick way to modify the code I make to work on the real thing)

`rstFrom` needs to contain only the columns of the 68-field table which are relevant to the table that I'm copying to at the moment (in this case, the FamilyHistory table which really just needs the `studentID` and `FamilyHistory`) - note that the original table did not assign unique `studentID`s, so I must use the name, school, and social to determine that I am dealing with the same child and look up their `studentID`

When this line of code runs I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '3061':

Too few parameters. Expected 1.
```

Clearly I have 1 parameter, it's:

`"select " & Flat & ".Student," & Flat & ".School," & Flat & ".Social," & Flat & ".FamilyHist from " & Flat & " WHERE 1=1"`

(which after parsing is):

`"select Demos.Student,Demos.School,Demos.Social,Demos.FamilyHist from Demos WHERE 1=1"`

The where 1=1 is required when working with Access VBA or else it only returns the first record which matches, not all matching records.

Has anyone else had this same problem as resolved it? I did notice one thing. When I change the parameter to:

`"select Demos.Student from Demos WHERE 1=1"`

It is able to get past this line no problem, although this causes issues later on when I need to read other data that I did not retrieve. I thought it was interesting, though, that the error seems to be coming from the SQL and not the OpenRecordset function.

Comment: Not sure why you are getting this error, but why not just pop the sql into a string and then pass that as the parameter?

Comment: Already tried. `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select Demos.Student,Demos.School,Demos.Social,Demos.FamilyHist from Demos WHERE 1=1")` gives me the same error.

Comment: Check the field names in the SQL vs what you have in table. I think, either the field name in above SQL is misspell or you dont have one or more field (of SQL statement) in the table.

Comment: Found the issue now. The `FamilyHist` field is actually stored as `Family Hist`. I need to write `Demos.[Family Hist]`. So @shahkalpesh was correct. If you write your comment in the form of an answer I'll gladly make it my accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the field names in the SQL vs what you have in table.

I think, either the field name in above SQL is misspell or you don't have one or more field (of SQL statement) in the table.

Answer (score 0):

The text parameters in the insert query need to have a single quote around them.  I ran into the same problem with a query using Visual C++.

Here's the code I ended up using...

```
void FileInterface::TblWrite(CDatabase* db, rec* r)
{
   string sqlQuery = "insert into THREATS(ID,CODE,ID,LAT,LON,SHOW_A,SHOW_B) Values(" +
      to_string((_Longlong)r->num) + "," +
      to_string((_Longlong)r->code) + "," +
      "'" + r->id + "'" + "," + 
      to_string((long double)r->lat) + "," +
      to_string((long double)r->lon) + "," +
      "1" + "," +
      "1" +
      ")";
   db->ExecuteSQL(sqlQuery.c_str());
}
```